# Nethereum 2.0.0-rc5 Miner

Tags: nethereum

In the previous version of Nethereum (1.0.6), I was able to do something like this:

```
var miningResult = await web3.Miner.Start.SendRequestAsync(200);
Assert.IsTrue(miningResult);
```

In 2.0.0-rc5 I get an error: Web3 does not contain a definition of Miner
How can I do the same in version 2.0.0-rc5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nethereum 2.0.0 has moved all the specific Geth methods to Nethereum.Geth. To start the mining process, you will need to use Web3Geth instead of Web3.

Steps:

1. install nuget package with Geth Install-Package Nethereum.Geth -Pre 2.
2. Create and use Web3Geth var web3Geth = new Web3Geth();
3. async web3Geth.Miner.Start.SendRequestAsync(6);

Comment: Thanks Juan.
So steps todo: 
1. install nuget package with Geth
    `Install-Package Nethereum.Geth -Pre`
2. then create and use Web3Geth
    `var web3Geth = new Web3Geth();           
      web3Geth.Miner.Start.SendRequestAsync(6);`

Comment: Yes, I will update the answer